# How can replugging a CPU fix something, and what is broken?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I just fixed my friend's PC in the weirdest way: nothing worked (didn't post, no beeps), but then I replugged the CPU because he said that did the trick once. To my amazement it actually solved the problem.

How could this be? It happens periodically from what he's told me, so something is probably broken. Would this be the CPU or the motherboard?

Things I tried before this: See if it would post after removing GPU, after removing the harddisk, and after removing the memory. These are all the components plugged in apart from PSU and fans.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your question is considered off-topic here on SuperUser because there is no problem to solve. For that reason it becomes highly speculative and as such its mostly considered opinion based. See the helpcenter on how to ask a question.

Comment: I can think of a few possible answers, but there is no way to know for certain unless we can inspect the computer before and after the solution. Because of this, like @LPChip mentions, this question is not well-suited for SuperUser.

Comment: @LPChip The problem to solve is which component to replace. How to make it stop requiring this replug now and then.

Comment: @music2myear I can check suggestions as they come up, the pc is within 2 meters

Comment: But... I'd consider the possibility that the CPU had become dislodged due to a move or drop or something, and was simply not contacting all of the necessary connectors. But, as we mentioned, there is no way to know.

Comment: Then you'll need to include the symptoms of the failure, the steps you've already tried, what precisely you observed upon opening the computer enough to get to the CPU, and how it is behaving now. Just to start with.

Comment: Ok, fair enough

Comment: What does "nothing worked" mean? Did the fans spin up? Did it beep?

Comment: Basically, we do best when there's still a problem to solve. You've solved yours so we start without that "benefit". Then, we need you to be our eyes and ears. We're a good brain, but we have to rely on your observational and descriptive skills to get the information necessary so that we can process a good answer.

Comment: The pin-to-socket connection can deteriorate to create high resistance.  Re-seating the CPU chip in the socket breaks all the contacts, and remakes the connections.  Contact solvent/cleaner could help alleviate this recurring issue, especially if there are contaminants, such as fingerprints/skin-oils.  Some premium types of sockets, e.g. MIL-SPEC, advertise "gas tight" connections that help avoid contact  deterioration.